# Arduino LED with Bluetooth in Android Studio! No error! But It Doesn't Burn

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

I want to light Arduino LED with Android Studio Bluetooth application.
I wrote all the codes. There is no problem, but the LED does not light. Android application works. But Arduino LED does not light up.
Could you please tell me what caused my error? Because I'm about to go crazy.

Arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  

int RX = 4;                   
int TX = 5;                       
 
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(RX,TX); 

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);          
  Serial.println("Already"); 
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (bluetooth.available()) {
    char c = bluetooth.read();

    if(c == 'a'){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Led High");
    
  }

if(c == 'b'){
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    Serial.println("Led Low");
  }

  }

}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
```

Activity_main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/highButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HIGH"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="679dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lowButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="low"
        android:layout_below="@+id/highButton"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="679dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String TAG = "-----------";

    private String macAddress = "";
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    Button high,low;

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    OutputStream outputStream;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        high = findViewById(R.id.highButton);
        low = findViewById(R.id.lowButton);



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 31) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 100);
                return;
            }
        }


        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            System.out.println("Name->" + device.getName() + "    " + "MAC->" + device.getAddress());
            if (device.getName().equals("HC-06")) {
                macAddress = device.getAddress();
                System.out.println("MAC - > " + macAddress);
            }
        }


        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);

        // Connecting to bluetooth device in a separate thread;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 31) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 100);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                    Log.d("Message", "Connected to HC-06");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth successfully connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Message", "Turn on bluetooth and restart the app");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Turn on bluetooth and restart the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);

                }

            }
        }).start();



        high.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    String a="a";
                    outputStream.write((a).getBytes());
                    Log.d("Command- >", a);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

        low.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    String b="b";
                    outputStream.write((b).getBytes());
                    Log.d("Command- >", b);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (bluetoothSocket != null) {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection closed");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error while closing the connection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be very happy if you answer.

Comment: Have you tried using a preexising bluetooth app to test the arduino?

Comment: Yes, i did try and its work. no problem

Comment: Ok, so the arduino seems to work just fine. You said in your question that the android app also works fine. How do you know that? Do you see the `Led High` and `Led Low` log output from your arduino?

Comment: Only use Arduino Yes, I see, But bot ardduino and Android, No, I dont see. By the way, thank you very much for trying to help. I pray a lot for you.

Comment: Could you please share the log output from your android app? Best would be to [edit] your answer and add it there

Comment: I solved the problem. The Tx and Rx cables needed to be swapped. Your very kind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a hardware problem.
Try uploading the Blink example?
If the LED blinks the Arduino is ok and it is a software problem
Maybe add some serial prints to both programs for debuging?